# How to arrange a list of elements in an array table in Latex

Tags: tables, lists

Suppose we have a list of elements {1, 2, ..., 18}.
I have to write a Latex program so that the elements can be written in the following dynamic table.
Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

[image: table-form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the following command `\Table` will do the job. The first argument is the number of columns wanted in the table and the second argument is the list of the numbers (separated by commas).

Eg: `\Table{4}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\Table} {mm}
   {\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#2}
    \int_do_until:nNnn {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist} < {#1+1}
       {\int_step_inline:nnnn 1 1 {#1-1} 
           {\clist_pop:NN \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpb_tl
            \tl_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl 
            \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {&}}
        \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpb_tl
        \tl_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl 
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\\ \hline}}
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist}
    \int_compare:nNnT \l_tmpa_int > 0
       {\int_step_inline:nnnn 1 1 {\l_tmpa_int - 1}
         {\clist_pop:NN \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpb_tl
          \tl_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl
          \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {&}}
        \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpb_tl
        \tl_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl 
        \int_step_inline:nnnn 1 1 {#1 - \l_tmpa_int}
          {\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {&}}
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\\ \hline}}
       \begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{c|}}
        \hline
        \l_tmpa_tl
        \end{tabular}}
\ExplSyntaxOff    


\begin{document}
\Table{4}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This fulfills my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Without using `xparse`, there is `listofitems` package which could be used with a `\foreach` from TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{,}
\newlength{\mysize}
\setlength{\mysize}{1cm}%size of the squares
\begin{document}
    \readlist\mylist{You,can,put,here,what,you,want,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \myrow using {int((\i-1)/5)},
        evaluate=\i as \mycol using {mod((\i-1),5)}] in {1,2,...,18}{
        \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size=\mysize, text height=.5\mysize, text depth=.2\mysize] at (\mycol*\mysize,-\myrow*\mysize) {\mylist[\i]};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent work!!! This fulfills my needs. This is very simple to use. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Tables in Latex can be made by using the tabular environment.
It starts by begining the environment and by telling how we want the data in each column to be aligned. An 'l' is used to align the items to the left. Then your data follows with a '&' to separate the columns and two backslashes to end the line. At the end you close the environment.
If you would like to add borders to your table you can do that by adding '|' in the header and \hline at the end of the rows.

**For example**
This code

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
1  & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5  \\ \hline
6  & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 \\ \hline
11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\ \hline
16 & 17 & 18 &    &    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Will result in this table:
[image]

I often use this online [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) tool for creating more complex tables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not the dynamic table. You just create manual table. This is not my requirement. If you change the list the table will be formed automatically.

Comment: So what do you mean exactly by a dynamic table then? Do you want some automated script to write the table for you?

Comment: Yes. {1,...,18} as an input will produce the above table. If we change the input list then the table will be changed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You decide the number of columns and, optionally, the column widths (all equal, in this case).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\dyntable}{omm}
 {% #1 is the cell width, if specified
  % #2 is the number of columns
  % #3 is the list of elements
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \arindam_dyntable:nnn { * } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \arindam_dyntable:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__arindam_dyntable_body_tl
\int_new:N \l__arindam_dyntable_count_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \arindam_dyntable:nnn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__arindam_dyntable_body_tl
  \int_zero:N \l__arindam_dyntable_count_int
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l__arindam_dyntable_count_int
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__arindam_dyntable_body_tl { ##1 }
    \int_compare:nTF
     { \int_mod:nn { \l__arindam_dyntable_count_int } { #2 } = 0 }
     { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__arindam_dyntable_body_tl { \\ \hline } }
     { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__arindam_dyntable_body_tl { & } }
   }
  \int_compare:nT
   {
    \int_mod:nn { \l__arindam_dyntable_count_int } { #2 } > 0
   }
   { % we need to fill the last line
    \prg_replicate:nn 
     {
      #2-1-\int_mod:nn { \l__arindam_dyntable_count_int } { #2 }
     }
     { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__arindam_dyntable_body_tl { & } }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__arindam_dyntable_body_tl { \\ \hline }
   }
  % print the table
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { * }
   { \begin{tabular}{|*{#2}{c|}} }
   { \begin{tabular}{|*{#2}{w{c}{#1}|}} }
  \hline
  \tl_use:N \l__arindam_dyntable_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\dyntable[1.5em]{4}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}

\bigskip

\dyntable{6}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}

\bigskip

\dyntable[3em]{6}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}

\bigskip

\dyntable{4}{
  apple, banana, orange, pineapple, cherry, mango, pear,
  apricot, peach
}

\bigskip

\dyntable[5em]{4}{
  apple, banana, orange, pineapple, cherry, mango, pear,
  apricot, peach
}

\end{document}
```

The list of items is traversed and each item is added to the body of the table; when we have reached the number of columns, `\\` is appended, otherwise `&`.

There is the problem of filling the last row, if short, which is done by adding the appropriate number of `&` and a trailing `\\`.

If no optional argument is specified, we pass `*`, which eventually means `c` column type. If a length is specified in the optional argument, we use `w{c}{<length>}` to get equal width columns.

[image]

Comment: Excellent!!!. This fulfills my need. Thank you for your quick answer.